# How can I set up rails sunspot solr production on debian 8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, debian, sunspot, production

I have two rails web applications with sunspot solr.

They works very well in development environment ( starting solr with `rake sunspot:solr:start` ), but in production environment I would like to install a separated multicore solr service using both of the rails application.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working solution:

1. Install Java8 using [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html) or [this](http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-debian/) instructions.
2. Download [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). I'm using version [6.2.0](http://xenia.sote.hu/ftp/mirrors/www.apache.org/lucene/solr/6.2.0/).
3. Unpack from solr-x.y.z.tgz the `install_solr_service.sh` script from the bin directory ( `bin/install_solr_service.sh` ).
4. Run this script with the name of the tgz file above as the first parameter ( `./install_solr_service.sh solr-x.y.z.tgz` ). It will install the solr for your system. The core will be in the `/opt/solr` directory, and the data will be in the `/var/solr`.
5. Start the service with `service solr start` command. The deamon will be executed in name of the `solr` user. (This user was created by the `install_solr_service.sh` script.) By default it will listen on port 8983.
6. You can access its management GUI via http://your_server_name:8983/solr/ . You can find more info [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr).
7. Create your solr cores:

> ```
> cd /opt/solr
> su - solr
> ./bin/solr create -c corename1
> ./bin/solr create -c corename2
> ```

8. Stop your solr with `service solr stop`
9. Change the solr core config to your config. You can find your config files under `/path/to/your/rails/application/solr/configsets/sunspot/conf` . Copy these file (lang subdirectory is not necessary to change) to your solr core config directory ( /var/solr/data/coranane1/conf/ ). Be sure, that after you change these files, the owner of them will be the solr user.
10. Start your solr with `service solr start`
11. Change your rails solr config file ( config/sunspot.yml ) to something similar:

> ```
> production:
>   solr:
>     hostname: localhost
>     port: 8983
>     path: '/solr/corename1'
>     log_level: WARNING
>     pid_dir: '/var/run'
> ```

12. Reindex solr in your rails application:

> ```
> RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:reindex
> ```

13. Enjoy. :) And don't forget to protect your solr admin interface ( `http://your_server_name:8983/solr/` ) via iptables or similar!